# Linking data in two Excel tables where row number does not align

Tags: excel, reference, alignment, row, formula

Table1 data starts at row 11 onwards and Table1 is called eSpace

Table2 data starts at row 18 onwards and column B heading is called Level

Entering =eSpace[Level] in Table2 row 18 retrieves the data from Table1 row 18.

How do I retrieve the data from row 11?

I have tried =eSpace[@Level]  and =eSpace[[#Data],[Level]]

I have Googled the problem and read many articles which tend to deal with more complex issues.

This seems such a simple problem and must have been met and easily dealt with but I cannot find any documentation which relates.

All help appreciated.

Comment: I would look at using index() with match(), match() will find the position and index() will return a result form that position in a different array. Many examples on here.

Comment: Many thanks I will add this to my list of options but I am seeking something much simpler. I know the tables will always be 7 rows apart (rows 11 and 18). I tried simply entering =B11 but this was not copied down so I used =If(1 = 1, B11, 0) and this did copy down but doesn't seem to me to be the 'right' solution. I am current considering using Offset which looks like =OFFSET(Table1,ROW(B11)+5-ROW(Table2),,1,1) which works but I have not yet understood why it is +5 and not +7. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`=INDEX(Table1[Espace],ROW()-ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[Level]]),1)`

This leverages the formula's own headering to establish the row. The columns must always be same number of rows. I'd use an array function for whatever you're doing, but I think this is what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks I will add this to my list of options but I am seeking something much simpler. I know the tables will always be 7 rows apart (rows 11 and 18). I tried simply entering =B11 but this was not copied down so I used =If(1 = 1, B11, 0) and this did copy down but doesn't seem to me to be the 'right' solution. I am current considering using Offset which looks like =OFFSET(Table1,ROW(B11)-12,,1,1) which works but I have not yet understood why it is -12. Thanks again.

Comment: Please include any additional information as an update to your question or comment if necessary. Do not add them as an answer.

Comment: I am using =OFFSET(eSpace,ROW(B11)+6-ROW(eBuilding),,1,1) which works well and I think is the simplest way of addressing the problem other than =If(1 = 1,B11, 0)